# jqgrid jsonReader

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way I can access the 'records' parameter of `jsonReader` in `loadComplete`?

```
jsonReader: {
records:"RECORDS",...

}
loadComplete:function() {
  getJSONReaderParam....
}
```

Also, Can I add a number to rowList on loadComplete?

```
rowList: [10,20,30],
....
loadComplete: function() {
  var getrowlist = $("#list").getGridParams("rowList");
 $("#list").setGridParam({rowList:[10,20,30,40});
```

}

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loadComplete takes a data [parameter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents).

```
loadComplete:function(data) {
    var records = data.records;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For replying. I am getting undefined when using the above solution. Instead I was using var records = $("#list").getGridParam("records"); and it works. I have another question. Can I append an extra number to rowList on loadComplete?

Comment: Strange, but glad you found the solution. For appending extra data you might have to create a custom jsonreader function: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function